# Android Studio forcefully restarts the computer

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problems with android studio. Every time it loads a project in android studio the computer restarts. It does not restart when opening the application since it lets me search for projects or create new ones, the problem is when loading a project, it does not go beyond build.gradle.

I emphasize that there are not temperature problems since the PC is capable of running several AVDs without any problem. I have also used programs to verify the operation and temperature of the components and everything is fine. I have also tried to change OS and the problem persists. I've also tried older versions of Android Studio and it still happens.

Edit: I have also tried switching from Windows to Ubuntu

The PC has a dedicated video card, an i5 11th and 16gb of ram. The board is asrock uefi. Can someone who has experienced this problem help me?

Comment: When Android Studio loads and builds a project this is done using gradle and this takes much CPU and RAM. If your computer reboots this is a clear indicator that something is wrong with your hardware (e.g. PSU problem). You can check e.g. using prime95 test if utilizing your CPU at 100% causes a reboot.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that there is a hardware problem, thank you.